# Compare dates linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql, xamarin, ssms

I cant seem to get my query to check the database if a date exists. Please help.

```
 DateTime value = new DateTime(2018, 10, 26);
 item = await table.Where(todoItem => todoItem.Date == value.date)
                   .ToListAsync();
```

I think the format which c# writes their dates and SQL are different so it cant find a match. Also the database is correctly linked to the app as I am able to query other rows in the same table.

Comment: Include the structure of your table

Comment: `todoItem.Date` might be including a time that `value` is not including.  It's often a good idea to force both dates to midnight for comparison.

Comment: @StevenWexler it works perfectly if I query the name for instance todoItem.Date == "Steven" so Im unsure as to why it isnt working. The data type ive given the 'date' field is DATE

Comment: @theGleep forcing row dates to midnight is horrible for performance (basically can't use indexes), [basically causes the sql to be non-sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable).

Comment: I'm not saying to do it in the DB, but in the comparison.

Comment: @theGleep the data type I'm using for the date field is 'DATE' instad of 'DATETIME'

Comment: That makes it less likely - but now we go to @StevenWexler's first comment.

Comment: @theGleep the code appears to send the *comparison* or *query* to the db to run.  It does not run client side.

Comment: @JohnDoe just include the table structure so there's no ambiguity.

Comment: @ErikPhilips ... argh!  That's not what the code *looks* like - but you're right.  double-argh!

Comment: @JohnDoe I assume this is [tag:linq-to-sql] or [tag:entity-framework]?

Answer (score 3):

As said before, this is likely due to the fact that your DateTime column in the database includes time information.

Rewrite your query like this:

```
DateTime value = new DateTime(2018, 10, 26);
item = await table.Where(todoItem => todoItem.Date >= value &&
                                     todoItem.Date < value.AddDays(1))
                   .ToListAsync();
```

This will retrieve all records that fall within the specified range (that is, dates that match the given day, and the DBMS will be able to use indexes that might be defined on the date-column.

Comment: Thank Frederik for your answer but it is still returning nothing for me.

Comment: You sure you have records in your table that match the criteria ?

Comment: The date type for the sql is 'DateTime' and the type for the c# is DateTime. I entered the date as above and the way the day is displayed in the database is "2018-10-26 00:00:00.000". Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong

Comment: Remove the `.Date` parts of the code sample - they are not needed.

Comment: @JohnDoe If you run `Select * from TableName WHERE ColumnName >= '20181026' and ColumnName < '20181027'` directly against the database (not through your app) is your row returned then?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Brandon's answer.. this is most likely happening due to `todoItem.Date` including the time portion of the `Date` property.

I **assume** the property `Date` is of type `DateTime`, so you could do this:

```
DateTime value = new DateTime(2018, 10, 26);
item = await table.Where(todoItem => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(todoItem.Date) == 
  value).ToListAsync();
```

> **DbFunctions.TruncateTime**
>
> When used as part of a LINQ to Entities query, this method invokes the canonical TruncateTime EDM function to return the given date with the time portion cleared.

Here is more information on [`DbFunctions.TruncateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.truncatetime(v=vs.113).aspx).

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: This will most likely prevent any indexes on the date-column to be used.

Answer (score -1):

This is most likely caused by including a time in your dates, and not formatting them to just the actual date string. You can resolve this by using the `.toLocaleString()` method. Something like this should work:

```
DateTime value = new DateTime(2018, 10, 26);
item = await table.Where(todoItem => todoItem.Date.toLocaleString() == 
  value.date.toLocaleString())
  .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: This will prevent the engine from using any Index (worst performance), [non-sargable query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable).

Comment: Please don't convert your date to a string in order to compare them ;...

Comment: 'DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'toLocaleString' and no extension method 'toLocaleString' accepting a first argument of type 'DateTime' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)